# WMIC output in batch. How to remove corruption?

Tags: batch-file, wmic

Want to detect if program is running in VirtualBox.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set count=0
for /f "tokens=1 delims==" %%a in ('wmic csproduct get name') do (
  set name!count!=%%a
  set /a count=!count!+1
)
if /i not !name1!==virtualbox (
echo NOT VIRTUALBOX
echo !name1!
) else (
echo VIRTUALBOX
echo !name1!
)
endlocal
```

But `!name1!` string is corrupt. By adding text AFTER `echo !name1!`, variable `!name1!` gets eaten by added text and text appears BEFORE string. Not able to perform `if` compare with such string. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap around another `for /F` loop:

```cmd
...
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('wmic CSProduct get Name') do (
    for /F "tokens=1 delims==" %%b in ("%%a") do (
        set "name!count!=%%b"
        set /A count+=1
    )
)
...
```

The problem is that `wmic` produces Unicode output, which `for /F` does not convert properly to ANSI text, it leaves some artefacts (orphaned carriage-return characters) behind; a second `for /F` loop removes them.

---

The command line `wmic CSProduct get Name` produces an output like:

> ```cmd
> Name
> VirtualBox
> ```

Therefore you could add the `skip=1` option to the outer `for /F` loop to not process the header. In addition, the option string `tokens=1 delims==` of the inner `for /F` loop does not make sense, because there should not appear any `=` anyway:

```cmd
...
for /F "skip=1 delims=" %%a in ('wmic CSProduct get Name') do (
    for /F "delims=" %%b in ("%%a") do (
        set "name!count!=%%b"
        set /A count+=1
    )
)
...
```

Alternatively, you could add the `/VALUE` option to the `wmic` command line to get an output like this:

> ```cmd
> Name=VirtualBox
> ```

In this case, the code needs to be adapted like this:

```cmd
...
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('wmic CSProduct get Name /VALUE') do (
    for /F "tokens=1* delims==" %%b in ("%%a") do (
        set "name!count!=%%c"
        set /A count+=1
    )
)
...
```

Comment: Thanks. This removes "hidden corruption" but still leaves some junk.If anyone else should struggle with this, "echo +!myvariable!+" to see how much whitespace there is between "+!myvariable!+" and use character removal technique as described in [ss64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html)

Comment: Well, the last approach (using `/VALUE`) prevents `wmic` from padding the output with spaces; for the standard table output format (no `/VALUE`), `wmic` does apply padding...